# how to load csv file data into pandas using request.FILES(django 1.11) without saving file on server

Tags: django, python-3.x, pandas, csv

i just want to upload .csv file via form, directly in to pandas dataframe in django without saving physically file on to server.

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
        try:
            from io import StringIO, BytesIO
            import io
            print("data===",request.FILES['file'].read().decode("utf-8"))
            # print("file upload FILES data=====",pd.read_csv(request.FILES['file'].read(), sep=','))
            #print(request.FILES)
            print("file upload data df=====11")
            mm = pd.read_csv( BytesIO(request.FILES['file'].read().decode("utf-8")))
            print("dataframe  data=====",mm)
            # import io, csv
            # urlData = request.FILES['file']
            # data = [row for row in (csv.reader(urlData))]
            # print("file upload data df=====222",data)

            # mm = pd.read_csv()

            #excel_file = request.FILES['file']
            # movies = pd.read_excel(request.FILES['file'])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        log.debug("Error in CheckThreadStatus api key required "+str(e))
        return Response(responsejson('api key required', status=404))
```

Comment: And what happens?

Comment: i am not getting print the df line: (print("dataframe  data=====",mm))

Comment: So what *do* you get?

Comment: its saying: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: please help me to load request.FILES['file'] data into pandas dataframe, the i want to save that df into pickle file on server folder

Comment: If you need bytes, don't call `decode` on the data.

Comment: if i do .... pd.read_csv(request.FILES['file'])
then it says: No columns to parse from file

Comment: You're probably exhausting the iterator in your first print call. Remove that.

Answer (score 2):

the ans is straight forward: that is

```
    pd.read_csv(request.FILES['file'])
```

works perfectly fine, the mistake i was doing is that.. my csv file was not in correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Check With
pd.read_csv('data.csv')  # doctest: +SKIP

If using post method you can try
getFile = request.FILE['file_name']

> > > pd.read_csv(getFile)  # doctest: +SKIP

Answer (score 0):

You can use **StringIO** for reading and decoding your `csv` :

```py
import csv
from io import StringIO


csv_file = request.FILES["csv_file"]
content = StringIO(csv_file.read().decode('utf-8'))
reader = csv.reader(content)
```

After reading you can populate your database like this :

```
csv_rows = [row for row in reader]
field_names = csv_rows[0]  # Get the header row
del csv_rows[0] # Deleting header after storing it's values in field_names

for index, row in enumerate(csv_rows):
   data_dict = dict(zip(field_names, row))
   Model.objects.update_or_create(id=row[0],
     defaults=data_dict
   )
```

> Make sure to validate data before inserting, if the data is critical.

> HINT: use django forms to validate for you.
>
> `from django import forms`